# How to show 'preview not available' message when REST is called directly from UI?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js, pdf-viewer

I want to display error message when document preview is not available.
I have used 'viewer.js' to show preview of document. All the coding part is done on back end. From UI only REST is called.
**My problem is since I have called documentPreview() REST service directly from HTML (and not from any 'view.js') I am not able to catch the response**. Here is the code:

```
<iframe id="sourceimage" scrolling="yes" height="800px" width="100%" style="background: #FFFFFF; overflow: hidden;" src="http://localhost:8080/project/Viewer.js/#<%CommonUtils.get("projectUrl")%>/testservices/rest/documents/documentPreview?id=<%=id%>"></iframe>
```

If preview is available (means if document is available in the database) then base64 will convert the code and will set converted code to response and preview will be displayed on UI. But if document is not available then nothing will be set to response object and on UI the spinner will keep get rotating because of which user might will think there is problem in the application but in reality document is not available that's why it is not getting displayed.

I tried to solve this issue by calling one private function from pdfViewer.js(required to display pdf files) to my xyzView.js but unable to call function. Any other solution?

Comment: Do you send back a 404 header if document does not exist?
Can you tell me more about the environment you are using (languages, frameworks, etc...)?

Comment: I am using java 7,spring framework and HTML 5 with javascript.
If document does not exist then from backend I have thrown customized exception as 'RecordsNotFoundException' but my problem is how am I supposed to catch the response/exception from backend because I have called REST service directly from html as mentioned above.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `viewer.js`. By REST services you have to send a 404 header to the client when a resource is not found. It should be possible with the java REST framework you are using... If this does not solve the problem (the pdf viewer does not react on the 404 header), then I think you should create a [viewer.js issue](https://github.com/kogmbh/Viewer.JS/issues).

Answer (score 0):

You should have your page respond with the HTML template for a preview not available instead of a 404 error.  That way it works in all browsers.